# ASP.NET MVC variable number of dropdown lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Consider the following question and potential answer: [ASP.Net MVC Multiple Drop Downs, Single List, Only Allow Unique Selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553344/asp-net-mvc-multiple-drop-downs-single-list-only-allow-unique-selections)

Ignoring most of the details, we can see that we can implement many dropdowns for a 1-m relationship like this:

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropwdownId1,Model.DropdownEntities) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropwdownId2,Model.DropdownEntities) %>
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropwdownId3,Model.DropdownEntities) %>
```

`DropdownId1`, `DropdownId2` and `DropdownId3` are properties easily added to the model if and only if we know exactly how many dropdowns we are going to display and postback.
However, I would like to implement a variable number of dropdowns. New dropdowns could, for example, be added dynamically by Javascript. Or the number of dropdowns displayed into the view could be dependent on some variable Property in `model`. say, `model.NumberOfDropDowns`.

How can I implement this?  How do I write a viewmodel, and controller action that can handle a variable number of dropdowns?

I have done a lot of reading on complex things like editor templates and blog posts where form elements are added dynamically, but I'm really having difficulty trying to figure out how this could be done. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your question how to dynamically add dropdowns using JavaScript?

Comment: No, my question is how to implement a view-model and postback controller to handle a variable number of dropdowns. This is why I also provided  an example where we use model.NumberOfDropDowns which decides how many dropdowns are created in the view.

Comment: Oh; OK. Good news is that we don't have postbacks in ASP.NET MVC, so you don't have to worry about that. Since your question is binding multiple values to a Controller Action, it'd help if you could edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: This would require a custom implementation. There are many ways to accomplish this task.

Comment: @TravisJ, could you please elaborate on the many ways? I don't expect a full on tutorial, but an explanation on what I should be googling could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A drop-down input still has only 1 submitted form value, so it's the same as any other variable-length view-model property: use a `List<T>`, like so:

#### ViewModel

```
class FooViewModel {
    public List<String> DropDownFields { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller Actions

```
[HttpGet]
ActionResult Index() {

    ViewData["dropDownSource"] = new List<SelectListItem>
              {
                   new SelectListItem
                   {
                        Text = "Test",
                        Value= "1"
                   },
                   new SelectListItem
                   {
                        Text = "Text",
                        Value= "2"
                   }
              };

    return View( new FooViewModel() );
}

[HttpPost]
ActionResult Index(FooViewModel vm) {

    for(int i = 0; i < vm.DropDownFields.Count; i++) {

        // for each dropdown
    }
}
```

#### View (aspx syntax)

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < vm.DropDownFields.Count; i++) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.DropDownFields[i], (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["dropDownSource"] ) %>
<% } %>
```